# Question about universal property of the localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory, localization

I have this doubt, that arises quite often when I work with localizations. Let $S\subset A$ be a multiplicatively closed set of a ring, and let $i:A\to S^{-1}A$ be the canonical homomorphism. Suppose that the ring homomorphism $f:A\to B$ induces a homomorphism $f':S^{-1}A\to B$ by the universal property of the localization. In general, to uniquely determine a homomorphism, it suffices to know how it is defined on the underlying set of its domain; however here the underlying set of $S^{-1}A$ is a set modulo an equivalence relation, say $X/\sim$. The fact that $f=f'\circ i$ tells me how $f'$ is necessarily defined on $X$ (uniqueness); since an homomorphism $S^{-1}A\to B$ must exist, can I conclude that $f'$ (that until now was a map $X\to B$) induces actually a well defined homomorphism $S^{-1}A\to B$, without making any check? Or a similar situation is that I define from nowhere a map $g:X\to B$, and it is such that $g\circ i=f$; can I conclude that $g$ is the unique homomorphism induced? (This seems the case of the second link below).

For example, I had this doubt in this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4346953/isomorphism-between-localizations), where I already made it explicit; also in the answer to this question ([Induced map between localizations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4331207/induced-map-between-localizations)), it was proven that $\varphi$ is well defined, but not a homomorphism. Can you give me a clarification about this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You do have to check that the induced map is a homomorphism. All you said is that there is a unique map $f':S^{-1}A\to B$ satisfying $f=f'\circ i$, and that there exists a homomorphism $S^{-1}A\to B$. Nothing in these (true) statements tells you that they're talking about the same map.

Comment: The universal property says the homomorphism $f'$ such that $f'\circ i=f$ exists and is unique. If the underlying map of $f'$ is uniquely determined, that $f'$ is necessarily an homomorphism. My doubt was mainly if it is well defined

Comment: The point of the universal property is that we don't need to find the induced homomorphism anymore. Its existence (and therefore well-definedness) is a given. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation of $S^{-1}A$ as equivalence classes is an artifact of your construction. The universal property guarantees that the $f'$ is well-defined on the equivalence classes.

In more detail, if $f\colon A\to B$ is such that for each $s\in A$ there exists $b_s\in B$ such that $f(s)b_s=1$, then we have a unique ring homomorphism $A\{x_s:s\in S\}\to B$ generated by $x_s\mapsto b_s$ and $a\mapsto f(a)$, where $A\{x_s:s\in S\}$ is the free ring expressions in variables $x_s$ with coefficients in $A$. Note that $f\colon A\to B$ factors through this ring homomorphism as $A\to A\{x_s:s\in S\}\to B$, where $A\to A\{x_s:s\in S\}$ sends $a\mapsto a1$.

The kernel of the ring homomorphism $A\{x_s:s\in S\}\to B$ includes the ideal generated by $\langle sx_s-1\rangle$. In fact, it is precisely that ideal, as the image of each $s\in A$ under the resulting quotient satisfies $sx_s=1$. But the ring homomorphisms $A\{x_s:s\in S\}\to B$ factors uniquely through the quotient by its kernel, whence its quotient is $S^{-1}A$ with $i\colon A\to A\{x_s:s\in S\}\to S^{-1}A$ and $f$ factoring uniquely as $f'i$ for $f'\colon S^{-1}A\to B$.

Notice that $f'$ is already defined (and a ring homomorphism) on the quotient, so on the set of equivalence classes that you're considering. In particular, you don't need to check it's well-defined again.

Comment: Thanks I liked your point of view

Answer (score 0):

The universal property of localization is the following: Given some multiplicatively closed set $S\subset A$, then for any ring homomorphism $f:A\to B$, s.t. $f(S)\subset B^\times$ there is a *unique* ring homomorphism $f':S^{-1}A\to B$ s.t. $f' \circ i=f$. That this holds true needs a proof. So once you check that this property holds, i.e. check that $f'$ is a ring homomorphism, check that $f' \circ i=f$ and so on.

The uniqueness bit is quite easy to see. Suppose $g:S^{-1}A\to B$ is some ring homomorphism s.t. $g\circ i=f$, then

$$ g(\frac{a}{s})=g(\frac{a}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{s})=g(i(a))\cdot g(\frac{s}{1})^{-1}=g(i(a))\cdot g(i(s))^{-1}=f(a)\cdot f(s)^{-1},\quad \forall a\in A,s\in S,$$
so $g$ is unqiue.

Comment: I know the universal property, I am asking this: let $f:A\to B, i:A\to S^{-1}A$, with $f$ inducing a unique homomorphism $f'S^{-1}A \to B$ by the universal property. If I find out the unique way that such $f'$ can be defined on the elements, then I don't need to check that it is a homomorphism, and this I understand. Now my doubt is: do I need to check that is well defined, since $S^{-1}A$ is a set modulo an equivalence relation? I'm quite convinced that I don't, but I might be confused.

Comment: @Dr.Scotti you need to check it once, when verifying the statement of the universal property. I think there is maybe some kind of misconception what universal property means. We call the universal property of the localization the above statement as we call something the universal property of direct limits, products, etc. however this does not mean that such a universal object exists for the given category. By verifying all the properties of $f'$ and constructing $S^{-1}A$ we show that such an object fulfilling the universal property of localization exists.

Comment: Yes I already proved the universal property of the localization in general, and in the course I'd say we assume that the localizations to multiplicatively closed subsets always exist in CRing